# cannot convert parameter 1 from 'ATL::CComPtr<T>' to 'int'

Tags: visual-c++, com

I'm migrating a project from vs 6.0 to vs 2008, I get the following error,

> error C2664: '_com_ptr_t<_IIID>::_com_ptr_t(int)' : cannot convert
>   parameter 1 from 'ATL::CComPtr' to 'int'

Output Window:

```
with
    [
        _IIID=_com_IIID<XML::IXMLDOMNode,& _GUID_2933bf80_7b36_11d2_b20e_00c04f983e60>
    ]
    and
    [
        T=XML::IXMLDOMNode
    ]
```

I am not able to fix this issue. The same is working fine in vs 6.0, I do understand that lot of things has changed from vs 6.0 to vs 2008.

Details on the error below:

```
bool CXMLHelper::GetFirstSubRecord()
{
bool bFound = false;

if ( m_spXMLNode == NULL ) return false;
if ( VARIANT_TRUE == m_spXMLNode->hasChildNodes() )
{
    typedef object_iterator<XML::IXMLDOMNode> iterator;
    for ( iterator oIte(m_spXMLNode->childNodes); oIte != iterator(); ++oIte )
    {
        XML::IXMLDOMNodePtr spNode(*oIte); // c2664 error
        if ( spNode->hasChildNodes() && !CXMLHelper::HasTextChild(spNode) )
        {

            m_spXMLNode = spNode;
            bFound = true;
            break; 
        }
    }
}
return bFound;
}
```

Definition of IXMLDOMNodePt:

```
_COM_SMARTPTR_TYPEDEF(IXMLDOMNode, __uuidof(IXMLDOMNode));
```

I understand that the error is because compiler not able to convert oIte from 'ATL::CComPtr' to 'int'. I'm very new to COM, Any help to fix this error is greatly appreciated. Thanks a lot in advance.

Regards,
Ankush.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that for some reason `*oIte` is of type `ATL::CComPtr` and `_com_ptr_t` (type of the template pointer `spNode`) has no constructor accepting `CComPtr&` but instead it has two constructors one accepting `int` and the other accpting `Interface*` and the compiler can't select the proper one. You have to explicitly say to the compiler that you want the constructor accepting `Interface*` and to achieve that you have to tell it to extract the encapsulated `Interface*` which is stored in member variable `CComPtr::p`:

```
XML::IXMLDOMNodePtr spNode((*oIte).p);
```

Comment: Wow sharptooth. That worked like charm. Thanks a lot for the fix and explanation.